# Using Python And Pandas To Split Excel Worksheet Into Separate Worksheets

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need a script to split a master worksheet (that contains over 50K rows) into separate worksheets that contain only 40 rows with no headings

After a bit of research I’ve managed to create a script that splits the master worksheet. However,  each of the worksheets contains the original heading and the rows are not split into 40 rows per worksheet.

I believe that when you split a worksheet using panda with data frames they will always contain a heading?  Any suggestions on how my python script can be modified to achieve what I need or is there a simpler way to achieve this without the need to use pandas and data frames?

Here is a link: https://github.com/lblake/sample-data to the some sample data

```
path = input('Enter file path to workbook name and extension, 
e.g. example.xlsx: ')
chunksize = int (input('Enter the row number you want to split the excel sheet at: ') )
destination = input('Enter folder path to where you want the split files stored. Press Enter to save in current location: ')

i = 0
df = pd.read_excel(path)
for chunk in np.array_split(df, len(df) // chunksize):
    chunk.to_excel(destination + 
'file_{:02d}.xlsx'.format(i), index=True)
i += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `groupby` and iterate. To ignore headers, specify `header=False` when writing to a `pd.ExcelWriter` object. The below example splits a dataframe of 10 rows into 2-row chunks.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(100).reshape((10, 10)))

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('file.xlsx')

for key, grp in df.groupby(df.index // 2):
    grp.to_excel(writer, f'sheet_{key}', header=False)

writer.save()
```

Answer (score 1):

I just copied your code and added `header=False`

```
path = input('Enter file path to workbook name and extension, 
e.g. example.xlsx: ')
chunksize = int (input('Enter the row number you want to split the excel sheet at: ') )
destination = input('Enter folder path to where you want the split files stored. Press Enter to save in current location: ')

i = 0
df = pd.read_excel(path)
for chunk in np.array_split(df, len(df) // chunksize):
    chunk.to_excel(destination + 
'file_{:02d}.xlsx'.format(i), index=True, header=False)
i += 1
```

and it worked for me.

Comment: Thanks adding the header=False option to my code fixed my issue